# Linear combination of trigonometric functions

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Consider the following equality:

$$a_1\sin(x) + a_2\sin^2(x) + ... +a_n\sin^n(x) = a_1\sin(x) + a_2\sin(2x) + ... + a_n\sin(nx)$$

where $a_1, a_2\dots, a_n \in \mathbb{C}, \;n \in \mathbb{N}$.

This equality clearly holds for $n = 1$ and for any $a_1 \in \mathbb{C}$. The trivial equality ($a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_n = 0$) also holds.

- Do there exists any other solutions? If so, are there infinitely many of such solutions?
- Do there exist other solutions if we constrain the domain of coefficients to $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $\sin3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3x,\, \sin5x=\ldots$

Comment: @Minz Actually, I'm asking for the coefficients to be equal on both sides.

Comment: in other words, you ask whether the system $\sin^2x-\sin2x,\ldots , \sin^nx-\sin nx$ is linearly dependent

Comment: Yes, that's equivalent.

Comment: The first term is useless. $n=2$ has no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $z:=e^{ix}$, you want to establish the identity

$$\sum_k a_k\left(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}\right)^k=\sum_k a_k\frac{kz-(kz)^{-1}}{2i}.$$

By identification of the polynomial coefficients, only $a_1$ can be nonzero.